# Creating SP 2010 site templates in Visual Studio

Tags: site-template, provisioning

I have been tasked with creating site templates which when used will provision the required lists and templates.

I have used this tutorial so far http://vimeo.com/23670570 and managed to make it work by essentially provisioning a carbon copy of the 'blog' site. Now I am trying to provision a site called **News Portal** using the same method but without any lists and using just one template called Default.aspx (the same as blog Default.aspx). the problem I get is that when I try and create the site I get the following error which im unsure of how to progress.

[image: My Error:- Failed to instansiate default.master]

the only thing i can find which relates to the error is this line from the default.aspx (carbon copy of blogs default.aspx)

`<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"  %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>`

Is this the cause of my error? if it is why does it work when I provision the whole blog site collection? Is there any fix that can be suggested that will allow the site to provision as essentially the branding will be overwritten by a feature with corporate branding in.

Sorry for the waffle and thanks in advance for the help.

If anything else needs clarification please ask.

Nicholas

My project looks like this

[image: Project Structure]

my webtemp xml looks like this

[image: Webtemp.xml]

my onet xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Title="$Resources:onet_BlogWebSite;" Revision="2" ListDir="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;" xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" UIVersion="4">
  <NavBars>
   <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Top;" Separator="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;" Body="&lt;a ID='onettopnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#' accesskey='J'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/a&gt;" ID="1002" />
<NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Documents;" Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;" Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;" Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" ID="1004" />
<NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Pictures;" Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;" Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;" Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" ID="1005" />
<NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Lists;" Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;" Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;" Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" ID="1003" />
<NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Discussions;" Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;" Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;" Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" ID="1006" />
<NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Surveys;" Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;" Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;" Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" ID="1007" />
   </NavBars>
   <DocumentTemplates>
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" Name="" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_None;" Type="100" Default="FALSE" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_None_Desc;" />
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Word97;" Type="101" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Word97_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\word\wdtmpl.doc" TargetName="Forms/template.doc" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Excel97;" Type="103" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Excel97_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\xl\xltmpl.xls" TargetName="Forms/template.xls" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Powerpoint97;" Type="104" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Powerpoint97_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\ppt\pptmpl.pot" TargetName="Forms/template.pot" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Word;" Type="121" Default="TRUE" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Word_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\word\wdtmpl.dotx" TargetName="Forms/template.dotx" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Excel;" Type="122" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Excel_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\xl\xltmpl.xlsx" TargetName="Forms/template.xlsx" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Powerpoint;" Type="123" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Powerpoint_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\ppt\pptmpl.pptx" TargetName="Forms/template.pptx" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_OneNote;" Type="111" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_OneNote_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\onenote\template.onepkg" TargetName="Forms/template.onepkg" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_FP;" Type="102" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_FP_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\fp\fptmpl.htm" TargetName="Forms/template.htm" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_BasicPage;" Type="105" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_BasicPage_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\blankpgs\_basicpage.htm" TargetName="Forms/_basicpage.htm" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
<DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_WebPartPage;" Type="106" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_WebPartPage_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\smartpgs\_webpartpage.htm" TargetName="Forms/_webpartpage.htm" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
<DocumentTemplate XMLForm="TRUE" Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_BlankForm;" Type="1000" Default="TRUE" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_BlankForm_Desc;">
  <DocumentTemplateFiles>
    <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\xmlforms\blank\template.xml" TargetName="Forms/template.xml" Default="TRUE" />
  </DocumentTemplateFiles>
</DocumentTemplate>
  </DocumentTemplates>
   <Configurations>
<Configuration ID="0" Name="Basic" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master">
  <SiteFeatures>
    <Feature ID="00BFEA71-1C5E-4A24-B310-BA51C3EB7A57" />
    <!-- Three-state Workflow Feature -->
    <Feature ID="FDE5D850-671E-4143-950A-87B473922DC7" />
  </SiteFeatures>
  <WebFeatures>
    <!-- TeamCollab Feature -->
    <Feature ID="00BFEA71-4EA5-48D4-A4AD-7EA5C011ABE5" />
    <!-- MobilityRedirect -->
    <Feature ID="F41CC668-37E5-4743-B4A8-74D1DB3FD8A4" />
  </WebFeatures>
  <Modules>
    <Module Name="BasicHome" />
  </Modules>
</Configuration>
  </Configurations>
  <Modules>
<Module Name="BasicHome" Url="" Path="">
  <File Url="default.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
    <NavBarPage Name="$Resources:core,nav_Home;" Url="~site" ID="1002" Position="Start" />
  </File>
</Module>
  </Modules>
   <ServerEmailFooter>$Resources:ServerEmailFooter;</ServerEmailFooter>
 </Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of googling i have found the answer in a blog from:-

http://seansharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/failed-to-instantiate-file.html

Failed to instantiate file "default.master" from module "DefaultMasterPage"
I ran into this error while trying to create a new Site Definition in SharePoint 2010.  It turns out that the TemplateName you select in your webtemp_custom.xml file:

Must match the folder in your SiteTemplates directory:

14/TEMPLATE/SiteTemplates/CustomSiteDefinitions